# Handling array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Given an array of Ruby hashes like this:

```
[{"lib1"=>"30"}, {"lib2"=>"30"}, {"lib9"=>"31"}, {"lib2"=>"31"}, {"lib3"=>"31"}, {"lib1"=>"32"}, {"lib2"=>"32"}, {"lib1"=>"33"}, {"lib3"=>"36"}, {"lib2"=>"36"}, {"lib1"=>"37"}]
```

How do I get a hash like this:

```
{"lib1"=>[30,32,33,37], lib2=>[30,31,32,36], lib3=>[31,36], lib9=>[31]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [{"lib1"=>"30"}, {"lib2"=>"30"}, {"lib9"=>"31"}, {"lib2"=>"31"}, {"lib3"=>"31"}, {"lib1"=>"32"}, {"lib2"=>"32"}, {"lib1"=>"33"}, {"lib3"=>"36"}, {"lib2"=>"36"}, {"lib1"=>"37"}]

a.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[k] ||= []
  h[k] << v
end
#=> {"lib1"=>["30", "32", "33", "37"],
#    "lib2"=>["30", "31", "32", "36"],
#    "lib9"=>["31"],
#    "lib3"=>["31", "36"]}
```

Alternatively:

```
Hash[a.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }]
```

If you're willing to use [Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/) then this becomes absurdly simple with [`collate`](http://rubyworks.github.com/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-class-Hash/api-method-Hash-h-collate):

```
a.inject(:collate)
```

Comment: Perfect.  I spent 2 days on this (learning ruby) and to see it explained so succinctly is sublime.

Comment: @cymorg I've added an alternative solution as well. I still think there must be a shorter way, but no matter what I do I can't escape the `map(&:to_a).flatten(1)`.

Comment: FYI, the OP example results show the values coerced to Fixnums. Ordinary nested iteration involves only one pass and fewer intermediate objects generated.

Answer (score 2):

```
t = [{"lib1"=>"30"}, {"lib2"=>"30"}, {"lib9"=>"31"}, {"lib2"=>"31"},
  {"lib3"=>"31"}, {"lib1"=>"32"}, {"lib2"=>"32"}, {"lib1"=>"33"},
  {"lib3"=>"36"}, {"lib2"=>"36"}, {"lib1"=>"37"}]
result = {}

t.group_by { |x| x.keys.first }.each_pair do |k, v|
  result[k] = v.map { |e| e.values.first }
end
```

Or, for a more purely functional version and fitting, sort-of, on the all-important one-line (it is Ruby, after all) ...

```
Hash[t.group_by { |x| x.keys[0] }.map { |k, v| [k, v.map { |e| e.values[0] }]}]
```

Comment: +1. Don't know why I didn't bother to try the `group_by` first.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate to Andrew's, avoids flatten and to_a, just nested iteration. Will gather multiple keys from element hashes in source array if present.

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |element,result|
  element.each do |k,v|
    (result[k] ||= []) << v.to_i
  end
end
```

Golfed to one-line:

```
a.each_with_object({}) {|e,r| e.each {|k,v| (r[k] ||= []) << v.to_i } }
```

I would note that this version examines each source element only once, while the to_a/flatten and group_by answers involve multiple iterations over the source or transformations of the source.

Andrew makes a good point that constant factors in big-O algorithm complexity are often a wash in reality.  I put together a [quick benchmark](https://gist.github.com/3929357) of the answers supplied so far (correcting them all to cast values to fixnum as the OP example implies).  My nested iteration approach does turn out to be somewhat (23-45%) faster with the OPs example source data:

```
ruby 1.9.2p318 (2012-02-14 revision 34678) [x86_64-linux]
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------------------
to_a_flat                  3.100000   0.000000   3.100000 (  3.105873)
to_a_flat_construct        4.060000   0.000000   4.060000 (  4.076938)
group_by_each              3.010000   0.000000   3.010000 (  3.015367)
group_by_each_construct    3.040000   0.000000   3.040000 (  3.050500)
nested_iter                2.300000   0.000000   2.300000 (  2.307776)
-------------------------------------------------- total: 15.510000sec

                               user     system      total        real
to_a_flat                  3.080000   0.000000   3.080000 (  3.096301)
to_a_flat_construct        4.050000   0.000000   4.050000 (  4.059409)
group_by_each              2.980000   0.000000   2.980000 (  2.997074)
group_by_each_construct    3.050000   0.000000   3.050000 (  3.057770)
nested_iter                2.300000   0.000000   2.300000 (  2.311855)
```

Comment: However, it's worth noting that the number of iterations has no effect on time complexity. I say this only because you seem to imply that iterating only once is more efficient (it may be, but only real benchmarks can show that).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall just because I'm procrastinating on real work, I tossed together little benchmark for ya.

Comment: +1 for real benchmarks `:)` (and I added the facets one to it to see how it faired… and boy is it slow—and now I'm working on making it faster)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the spectrum; you can avoid each_with_object by defining the resulting Hash up front and use a regular .each loop. I find it easier to read than the former approach.

```
grouped = {}
hashes.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key, value|
    (grouped[key] ||= []) << value.to_i
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar to DigitalRoss's, but I would do it in place:

```
array.group_by{|h| h.keys.first}.each{|_, a| a.map!{|h| h.values.first}}
```